# Trim product name based on manufacturer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, list.phtml

I have a shop with many SKU's. I've recently added the manufacturer name attribute (e.g. Nike) to the catalog/product/list.phtml. As a result I now have duplication as the manufacturer shows before the product name, which also contains the manufacturer name (e.g. Nike Nike Shoes).

I wonder if anyone can advise of a PHP function where by I can trim the 'name' attribute by the 'manufacturer' attribute.

For example, if 'manufacturer' attribute = 'Nike' then remove 'Nike ' from 'name' attribute.

Here's the current code I have in list.phtml:

```
<?php
    echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name')
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand why to add the Manufacturer name in the name of the product .. I think you are fighting against a self-created problem

Comment: You're correct but we have 1000's of SKU's, and the alternative is going through each product and removing the manufacturer reference in the product name.

Comment: what about doing the job directly in mysql (remove the manufacturer name in the product name)?  .. it would be done in a single query once forever ..

Comment: see my modified answer .. it should do your job

Comment: But presumably I would have to do a separate query for each brand (e.g. Nike, Adidas, Puma and so on...)?

Comment: you should make a JOIN to retrieve the manufacturer from the product attribute
An alternative to "correct" your DB is to use the magento API and do the job programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `str_repalce()`

```
str_replace('//menufacture name ','//replace value', $_product->getName());
```

update code

```
$lowermenu=strtolower($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
$menufacture=array($lowermenu,$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));

    echo str_replace($menufacture,' ',$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'));
```

you can reference example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Thank you Qaisar. But I have many manufacturer names. Within this argument is there a way I can automate the picking up of the 'manufacturer' attribute and subsequent removal from the 'name' attribute?

Comment: how you are showing.paste that code i write full code for you.

Comment: I've added my current code to the original question Qaisar. Showing how I am currently picking up the manufacturer and product name.

Comment: updated the code...

Comment: Seem to get an error with this whereby only one product now shows on the listings page.

Comment: updated code and tested too there is no error in that.

Comment: You are replacing **every occurrence** of the `$manufacturer`into the product name .. and it is prone to be buggy IMHO

Comment: Hi Qaisar, run into a problem with the above code where a manufacturer attribute with '&' in it seems to be ignored by the script. Is there any edit I can do to get around this?

Comment: @YorkieMagento what is product name and what is manufacture name

Comment: It is 'Dolce & Gabanna' and 'Dolce & Gabanna T-Shirt'

Comment: @YorkieMagento check the space issue in manufacture name at the end

Comment: Hi Qaisar, but the code you've provided above works on all other brands. Apart from this and one other with '&' in the manufacturer title.

Comment: @YorkieMagento i tested this code it is working `echo str_replace('Dolce & Gabanna',' ','Dolce & Gabanna T-Shirt');`

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the opposite. "if name begins with 'Nike'" then don't print the manufacturer ...

```
$_product_name = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
$_manufacturer = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');

if (0!==strpos($_product_name, $_manufacturer)) {
    echo $_manufacturer;
}
echo $_product_name);
```

But see my comment ..

*Edited as per your current code*

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<?php

 if($_Product->getManufacturer())
 {
    str_replace($_Product->getManufacturer()," ",$_Product->getName());
 }
```

Comment: Hi Arunendra - this results in an error for me where only one product shows on the listing page (there are 100's). I've added my current code to the original question.

Comment: I think you should assure to remove the Manufacturer only at the very beginning of the Product name .. otherwise you could make "ThenikeShoe" look like "TheShoe""